# Transform multiple objects into one object with same key, value as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So here is the deal. I have an array that contains a bunch of objects that look something like this:

```
[{
  "this": 5,
  "that": 300,
  "those": 15
},
{
  "this": 6,
  "that": 301,
  "those": 16
},
{
  "this": 7,
  "that: 302,
  "those": 17
}]
```

What I want, is an object, that looks like this:

```
{
  "this": [5, 6, 7],
  "that": [300, 301, 302],
  "those": [15, 16, 17]

}
```

I don't really know what to call this and by what I searched for, I couldn't find anything similar that would help me.

Comment: I refer to this as transposing an array from row/column to column/row.

Comment: [**Here is a jsperf**](http://jsperf.com/array-reduce-vs-double-for-loop) for the two suggested answers. The double for loops are faster in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For older browsers (i.e. IE8), `reduce` is not available. If you still want to support these, you can try:

```
var arr = [{
    "this": 5,
        "that": 300,
        "those": 15
}, {
    "this": 6,
        "that": 301,
        "those": 16
}, {
    "this": 7,
        "that": 302,
        "those": 17
}];

var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var x in arr[i]) {
        if (!result[x]) {
            result[x] = [];
        }
        result[x].push(arr[i][x]);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

EDIT: This will also allow modification of the source array without changing the converting code.

Comment: Thanks. :) I made one too, but forgot to save it.

Comment: Also added a [**jsperf**](http://jsperf.com/array-reduce-vs-double-for-loop) of the two suggested answers.

Comment: This is excellent! I chose this one because it works everywhere without any special needs.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var a = [{
    "this": 5,
    "that": 300,
    "those": 15
},{
    "this": 6,
    "that": 301,
    "those": 16
},{
    "this": 7,
    "that": 302,
    "those": 17
}];

a = a.reduce(
    function(obj, item){             // Map the item to the object.
        obj.this.push(item.this);
        obj.that.push(item.that);
        obj.those.push(item.those);
        return obj;
    },
    {"this":[],"that":[],"those":[]} // Default (empty) object.
);
```

This uses [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: You forgot to assign `a` the reference to the new array. Could assign it to a new variable ofc.

Answer (score 0):

#### Fancy reduce + concat variation

```
[{"this": 5, "that": 300, "those": 15}, {"this": 6, "that": 301, "those": 16 }, {"this": 7, "that": 302, "those": 17}]

.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return {
        "this":  [].concat(prev["this"], [curr["this"]]),
        "that":  [].concat(prev["that"], [curr["that"]]),
        "those": [].concat(prev["those"], [curr["those"]]),
    };
})
```

Result:

```
{"this":[5,6,7],"that":[300,301,302],"those":[15,16,17]}
```

Test in in console yourself.

By using `concat` we don't have to pass empty `{"this":[],"that":[],"those":[]}` initial value.

#### Version #2. Universal code

```
[{"this": 5, "that": 300, "those": 15}, {"this": 6, "that": 301, "those": 16 }, {"this": 7, "that": 302, "those": 17}]

.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    for (var key in prev) {
        prev[key] = [].concat(prev[key], curr[key])
    }
    return prev;
})
```

As you can see this version doesn't make any assumptions about key names.